# Julia: JULIA_LOAD_PATH not defined when trying to set value

Tags: path, package, julia, ijulia-notebook, load-path

I am trying to set the JULIA_LOAD_PATH as already discussed here [Github issue](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/29513) and [Julia Docu](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/environment-variables/).
I try to run
`JULIA_LOAD_PATH= "/mypath/bla:$JULIA_LOAD_PATH"`
in a julia-session, but get the following error:

```
UndefVarError: JULIA_LOAD_PATH not defined

Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at In[23]:1
```

I did already do a `using Base` statement, in case the variable is defined in the Base module, but it did not really help.

How can I add a folder to the julia load-path variable, such that I can import packages from there?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JULIA_LOAD_PATH is a system environment variable you may set outside of Julia in your system.  You are looking for `Base.load_path()`, which can be displayed with

```
julia>Base.load_path()
```

and added to with

```
julia>push!(Base.load_path(), "mydirectory")
```

See also help for `LOAD_PATH`.

Comment: Docs are confusing. Help for ``LOAD_PATH`` recommends precisely what the OP tried. I don't see a reference to ``Base.load_path()`` in these docs: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/environment-variables/  Having said that, querying ``Base.load_path()`` returned a list, but pushing with ``push!(Base.load_path(), "mydirectory")`` gave me ``"ERROR: LoadError: syntax: missing comma or ) in argument list"`` (with perfectly formed directory that I can ``cd()`` to)...

Comment: PatrickT, this may be a version issue, if you have an older Julia installation.  See the current 1.6 docs at https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/constants/#Base.LOAD_PATH, which do mention load_path() though not with its usage.

Comment: Thanks Bill. I have the latest Julia (stable release) and the docs make for difficult reading, but after commenting above I found that ``push!(LOAD_PATH, "mydirectory")`` worked for me, for whatever reason... :-)